# asp.net control renders outside of border on server

Tags: asp.net

I am using a custom asp.net time picker control which I found [here](http://timepicker.codeplex.com/).  It works great but I've run into one issue.  When I'm testing locally it displays fine:

[image]

When I publish the web app to our server though it displays outside of the border.
[image]

I placed a border around the control just for testing purposes.  It displays funky whether or not a border is defined.  Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?  I'm definitly not a css guru but maybe there's something there?  Thanks for any suggestions, see code below.

CSS

```
 .timePicker
{    
   border-bottom:solid 2px Silver;
   border-left:solid 2px Silver;
   border-top:solid 2px Silver;
   border-right:solid 2px silver;    
}
```

ASPX

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="When will you be closing?"></asp:Label>

 <MKB:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelectorClose" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="timePicker"                 
            MinuteIncrement="1" 
            DisplaySeconds="False" 
            Height="20px">
 </MKB:TimeSelector>
```

Comment: You're probably in compatibility mode.

Comment: @SLaks Of course!  Funny how I've helped others with that same suggestion and completely forget it when I have a problem.  Thanks for the tip, that cleared things right up :)